# Getting components of NSURL as phone number

Tags: ios, swift, nsurl

I have an NSURL being returned to me as something like

```
tel:555-555-5555
```

I can recognize it as a telephone by identifying the NSURL's scheme as "tel" using

```
let url = NSURL(string: "tel:555-555-5555")
if url.scheme == "tel" {
    // it's a telephone number
}
```

But I can't find a command to get the actual phone number component. The phone numbers can come back much more messy than the example I gave, so I thought it would be much safer to ask if there was a way to get the phone number component directly instead of saving as string and clipping out the scheme.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `resourceSpecifier`:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "tel:555-555-5555")!
if url.scheme == "tel" {
    let number = url.resourceSpecifier
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, never heard of resourceSpecifier. Works perfectly. Thank you!